# Avi does not play full screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, avi

I have several avi video files. The files that have width x height as (512 x 288), (640 x 384) and (544 x 304) play full screen on Windows Media Player and Real Player, but the files that have w x h as (720 x 576) does not play full screen on WMP and RP.

Comment: How do they not play full screen? Can't you activate full screen? Or are they shown differently?

Comment: @slhck, with the troubled videos, when I use Alt+Enter, it does not occupy the 100% area of screen whereas the normal ones do.

Comment: What resolution is your display (in pixels)?

Comment: through Windows (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution>) it shows 768 x 1366 , when i see it through the "Intel Graphics and media control panel"(graphics card app) it shows 1366 x 768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display has an aspect ratio of

```
1366/768 = 1.77
```

Let's look at the aspect ratios of each of the files provided where you claim they work fine:

```
512/288 = 1.77
640/384 = 1.66
544/304 = 1.78
```

Great – the aspect ratio is almost identical. When you play those files in full screen, you will only see a tiny black border. Now, the file that does not cover the full screen has a totally different aspect ratio – it is not as wide as the others:

```
720/576 = 1.25
```

Of course it will never cover the full screen's area, since it has completely different dimensions. Unless you want to squeeze the video, you *need* to see it with black bars to the left and right ([pillarboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillarboxing)).

Comment: will changing the screen resolution temporarily help? just to watch videos and then change it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it will look stretched as well.